# how do I ensure that the config file is identical to the vshost.exe config file

Tags: .net, visual-studio, config

This question has been edited after a poster suggested it needed improvement:

This is a Visual Studio behaviour question.  If I make config file changes using an XML editor, do I have to edit both the vshost.exe config file and the regular config file to ensure they are always the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project + Add New Item, select "Application Configuration File".  Edit *that* one.  The IDE makes sure that it gets copied to the bin\Debug directory and that the vshost version will match.

Comment: in my case vshost.exe.config does not match my app.debug.config, in my WPF project. If i set the debug mode and build, the <appname>.exe.config and <appname>.vshost.exe.config have different value, as if vshost.exe.config was coping value from the app.config and not app.debug.config eventhough i build in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I performed the following test.

I edited only the .vshost.exe config file and executed the program in the IDE.  After running the program, the two files have the same time stamp so presumably they are the same (although I don't have a binary diff program to prove it and may be functionally identical files would still look different to a binary diff program).  It is nice that Visual Studio makes them identical, but the problem is that my edits were lost, that is, the regular config file parameters appear in both config files.

The rule of operation should be: always edit the regular config file.

Comment: I realize question was a long time ago, but for any who don't know, you do have a binary diff program built in to Windows. `fc /b file1 file2`. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The vshost.exe.config file is replaced each time you build.  But that said, you should not edit configuration files in the Debug or Release folder.  If you edit the app.config in your solution folder and you will be fine.  Furthermore, you should not deploy the vshost.exe or the vshost.exe.config as those are used only by the debugger.

Comment: Actually, just running the program inside the IDE causes the vshost.exe config file to be updated.  You don't have to build.

Comment: I have no app.config in the solution folder.  There is an App file of type "Windows Markup File" but I don't think that is what you mean.  The config files are in the bin\debug folder.